# How do you apply never_cache to a third party Django app's urls?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the `@never_cache`decorator in the `urls.py`. I think one can use

```
url(r'^about/', never_cache(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about_us.html"))),
```

but a lot of times I am using external apps and all I do is `url('', include(shop.urls))` One example is `django-oscar`. Now do I in this case apply never_cache to that?

Answer (score 1):

You might find luck with this approach from [django-snippets](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/355/):

```py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

def never_cache_patterns(prefix, *args):
    pattern_list = [], tterns,
    for t in args:
        if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)): 
            t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)
        elif isinstance(t, RegexURLPattern):
            t.add_prefix(prefix)

        t._callback = never_cache(t.callback)
        pattern_list.append(t)

    return pattern_list


urlpatterns = never_cache_patterns('',
    (r'foo/$', 'myview')
)
```

It doesn't look like there is a way to do it in a cleaner fashion.

If you want to apply it to a set of urls from another app which you cannot edit then you can try:

```
uncached_patterns = never_cache_patterns('',
   url(r'^$', include('shop.urls')),
   )

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    include(uncached_patterns),
    # other patterns
    # eg. url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),
    # ...
)
```

Comment: this doesn't really work. tried never_cache_patterns('', include('shop.urls'))

Comment: I've updated the answer. Honestly I'm not in a position to test it thoroughly, so I apologise if it doesn't work. The update is based on my general knowledge of the urlpattern setups.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me at Django 1.11 (staying with the example of `shop.urls`):

```python
uncached_patterns = [
    url(urlpattern.regex.pattern, never_cache(urlpattern.callback), name=urlpattern.name) for urlpattern in shop.urls.urlpatterns
]

urlpatterns += [
    url('', include(uncached_patterns))
]
```